# Jest simulate not showing text on textbox

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Here is my test script to test 'SearchBox' component using Jest/Enzyme -

```
   test('searchbox input!',()=>{
const wrapper=global.mount(<SearchBox  onTextChangedFunc={dummyFunction}></SearchBox>)
const textBox=wrapper.find('#inputText')
textBox.simulate('change',{target:{value:'p12346997'}})
wrapper.update();
console.log(wrapper.debug());
})
```

Here is the dummyFunction -

```
function dummyFunction(e)
{    
}
```

I can not figure out why the console.log at the last line does not show the updated text. This is what I am getting on the console -

```
 <SearchBox onTextChangedFunc={[Function: dummyFunction]}>
<div className="textBoxContainer" style={{...}}>
  <input id="inputText" className="customTextbox" required={true} onChange={[Function: dummyFunction]} onBlur={[undefined]} />
  <label className="lbl" name="placeholder_label" onClick={[Function: bound labelClicked]} />
  <label id="inputError" className="err" />
</div>
```

I was expecting to see the text '**p12346997**' on the console log as a value for the input (with id "inputText").

Please let me know if I can give more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding it to an empty function, what you can do here is that you can simply

```
expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The reason for that is, that I guess you have attribute `value={this.state.customTextBox}`, that updates the value in state and then binds it to input. So in order to see that I would suggest to ways. You either expect that dummyFunction to have been called with that object

```
const dummyFunction = jest.fn();

expect(dummyFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith({target:{value:'p12346997'}});
```

or if you are binding the value with the state, simply check if the object in state has that value:

```
 expect(wrapper.state().myInput).toBe('p12346997');
```